# How do I read parquets in Pyspark which were created by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am trying to read parquet files using Pyspark from a folder which has few parquet files created by Pandas.
This is how parquets created

This is how I created a parquet using Pandas

```py
df= pd.DataFrame({'foo':[2,1], "bar": [1,2], 'for': [3,2]})
df.to_parquet('./Dir/filename.parquet')

spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
dwh= spark.read.format('parquet').option('header', True).load('./Dir/')
```

When I do so, I get a big error. But when I read the same from pandas using `read_parquet()` it works. Also the parquets created by Pyspark are working with Pandas but not vice versa. below is the part of the error

```sh
21/09/23 16:59:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:450)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:496)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=file:/home/ravi/Documents/outputParq/Hisar_v4pandas/2021-09-23 16:31:24 to 2021-09-23 16:32:24.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=28960; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:463)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
        at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
```

Comment: How did the parquet files are created by Pandas, can you share them?

Comment: Can you try and load a specific file directly instead of pointing to a folder? e.g. `.load(./Dir/my_file.parquet`? Also, the header option doesn't apply when reading parquet files.

Comment: Hi @pltc thanks for your response. I have edited the post please check.

Comment: Thanks @ScootCork I have tried that also. But the same error.

Comment: @RaviTejaPavuluri I tested with your sample parquet and it works just fine. Can you try again with your sample parquet?

Comment: Hey thanks @pltc It worked for me now, the issue was there is a space in the fine names. Im sorry bothering you with such a silly question thanks for your time.